# Azure AD B2C with OpenID Connect getting error AADB2C90238: The provided token does not contain a valid issuer

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

- I added and configured an OpenID Connect Identity Provider.
- I set the return URL in the provider correctly.
- I'm using the "Sign up and Sign in" user flow -- not a custom policy.

Running through the user flow, I ultimately get redirected to my application .../MicrosoftIdentity/Account/Error (or if I set return url to jwt.ms, I get the same error) with the page indicating the error
**AADB2C90238: The provided token does not contain a valid issuer**

How can I even see the issuer in the token? (It's all handled inside AD B2C service).

I can see what's listed in the provider's *.../.well-known/openid-configuration* endpoint. I guess that's what's not matching in the token. I've seen suggestions of using Application Insights Logs to view the token -- but, apparently, that can only be done with custom policies.

Is there another way to tell AD B2C not to validate the issuer? Or is another way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

Open Id configuration is like below:

***Where the **metadata url** is*** **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`**

[image]

***Authorization request looks like below:***

```
https://kavyasarabojub2c.b2clogin.com/kavyasarabojub2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_newSignupSignin&client_id=xxxxx5&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

***I received the same error :***

- With redirect uri: https://jwt.ms

  Error: invalid_request
  **AADB2C90238:** The provided token does not contain a valid issuer. Please provide another token and try again.

[image]

- With redirect uri: `https://kavyasarabojub2c.b2clogin.com/kavyasarabojub2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`

[image]

So here the redirect Uris are correct and need to correct the metadata url :

Created an OpenId provider with meta data url  having tenantId instead of organizations .

***`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`***

[image]

Run the user flow with this Identity provider
***Could login successfully and get the access token  with endpoint***

> **Note: make sure it has the policy included:**

I have p=B2C_1_newSignupSignin

`https://kavyasarabojub2c.b2clogin.com/kavyasarabojub2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_newSignupSignin&client_id=1xxxxe2a5&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login`

[image]

Here the issuer is of V2 endpoint  "iss": ***`"https://kavyasarabojub2c.b2clogin.com/<tenantId>/v2.0/"`***

**Reference :** [Web sign in with OpenID Connect - Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect)

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this does not really help. I am already using the correct metadata URL. My problem is specifically that the ID Provider is returning a token with iss being different from the metadata -- and I cannot see the iss value in the token because it all happens inside AD B2C -- unless I want to write all the code myself.

Comment: Can you provide the metadata url and some details of your configuration. The iss calim can be seen in the decoded token as in the answer above "iss". Also can you check what's there in Issuer in the properties section .Check edit above for reference

Comment: The issuer in the metadata is X. The iss claim in the token is Y. This is causing the error. However, the details are hidden from me because AD B2C is handling the messaging to/from the ID provider. It would be nice if I could a) optionally not validate the isssuer, and b) be informed of the details of the error, by being provided all the claims. ... I should add that I have since determined the iss claim on my own and I've implemented a work-around to deal with the misbehaving ID provider. Thanks for your input!